# Problema ao deixar a largura da textarea automática

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Salve a todos, estou tendo problemas em deixar que a largura de uma textarea acompanhe o tamanho da linha, tendo em vista que o tamanho inicial dela atualmente não se expande.

Meu objetivo é deixar que a textarea aumente apenas a largura conforme o usuário vá escrevendo.

Segue o código atual:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
           <p>&nbsp;
        <textarea name="textarea" wrap="wrap" id="the_textarea" rows='1' class="textarea-cliente" placeholder="nome"></textarea>, esta textarea deveria expandir APENAS sua largura para acompanhar o tamanho do texto inserido dentro dela.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -6px;
    border: none;
}

.textarea-cliente {
    min-width: 25%;
    height: 24px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Gostaria de um luz neste problema.
Desde já, agradeço a compreensão.

Comment: O html esta quebrado, na div do textarea, no caso o que você quer eu nao entendi bem.

Comment: Cara vc colocou um textarea dentro de um parágrafo? Não entendi... Sua estrutura de HTML parece meio equivocada... e vc está usando a class `col-7` isso vai deixar não vai deixar o elemento ficar com 100% da largura da tela, se é isso que vc quer, pois não deu para entender bem....

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Atualizado, peço desculpas pelo problema.

Comment: @hugocsl Estrutura refeita, desculpe pelo erro.
Sim, tinha colocado textarea dentro de um parágrafo. Não conhecia esta limitancia da col-7, tendo em vista que a utilizei em prol de apenas aumentar a sua largura.

Comment: sim mas seu problema você quer que o textarea va se expandindo conforme for escrevendo ou conforme o tamanho da pagina ?

Comment: Você precisa estruturar seu grid corretamente usando `.container > .row > .col` ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)). Você também não parece estar usando as [estruturas de formulário](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-controls) corretamente (`.form-group > textarea.form-control`).

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Conforme for escrevendo.

Comment: tanto largura quanto altura ?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Apenas largura

Comment: Na verdade o que vc quer é que conforme o usuário for digitando a `<textarea>` vai ir crescendo automaticamente é isso? Ou vc que uma `<textarea>` já com 100% da largura?

Comment: @hugocsl Sim, que a <textarea> cresça automaticamente.

Comment: Isso não é possível. vc precisa determinar um tamanho para ela, seja 10% da largura da tela ou 100% da largura. Ela não vai crescer na horizontal conforme vc vai digitando, isso não é um comportamento possível de se incluir em uma <textarea> com CSS

Comment: @hugocsl Entendo, tentarei buscar outras alternativas para tal solução.
Obrigado pela informação!

Comment: @Nithogg realmente eu nunca vi, o que eu recomendaria seria, deixar ele em 100% a div limitando ele, e fazer um auto recize pra baixo

Comment: @Nithogg algo parecido com isso aqui http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Comment: @Bulfaitelo Com base nessas informações, vou procurar uma solução diferente ou parecida, como a sua sugestão, mas agradeço a informação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com JavaScript você pode verificar se a largura do scroll é maior que a largura do elemento e assim ajustar a largura de forma dinâmica conforme vai digitando:

```js
document.getElementById('the_textarea').addEventListener('input', function(){
   
   var largura = this.offsetWidth; // largura do textarea
   var hscroll = this.scrollWidth; // largura do scroll
   
     if(hscroll > largura){
        this.style.width = hscroll+"px";
     }else if(!this.value){
        this.style.width = "auto";
     }

});
```

```css
textarea {
    resize: none;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -6px;
    border: none;
}

.textarea-cliente {
    min-width: 25%;
    height: 24px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
           <p>&nbsp;
        <textarea name="textarea" wrap="off" id="the_textarea" rows='1' class="textarea-cliente" placeholder="nome"></textarea>, esta textarea deveria expandir APENAS sua largura para acompanhar o tamanho do texto inserido dentro dela.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A única coisa que não consegui foi fazer o textarea diminuir de tamanho caso seja usada a tecla do <kbd>backspace</kbd>, porém coloquei um `else if` que volta ao tamanho normal caso o textarea fique vazio.

Comment: Uau, pensei que teria que mudar minha estratégia na página, obrigado mesmo, vai ser muito útil!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar!

```js
 var tx = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <style>
  textarea{width: 100%;overflow-y: hidden;}     
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <textarea placeholder="Escreva seu texto aqui..."></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Comment: A questão da pergunta é aumentar a largura, e não a altura.

Comment: Eu entendo Sam, mas se ele precisar da altura ele pode usar o meu código tbm só queria ajudar

Comment: Obrigado @Cleber, futuramente pretendo usar esta mecânica de altura também!